# PHP Dynamic button value from array

Tags: php

this is my problem:

```
    echo '<form class="dugme" method="post" name="$b" value="">
<button type="submit">Pusti</button>
</form>';
```

I have defined $b variable, and want to draw this on page with for loop ($b=0; $b<=10; $b++) .

But in every scenario with " ", ' ' ... i get name="$b" ;

My code:

```
for ($b=0; $b <= 10; $b++){
echo '<form class="dugme" method="post" name="$b" value="">
<button type="submit">Pusti</button></form>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to concatenate properly

```
for ($b=0; $b <= 10; $b++){
echo '<form class="dugme" method="post" name="'.$b.'" value="'.$b.'">
<button type="submit">Pusti</button></form>';
}
```

**note :** inside the single quotes everything consider as string . you need to escape it or you need to concatenate like this